# Magic function timeit

Tags: python, ipython, timeit, magic-function

I'm using the magic %%timeit function to get the time it takes to execute some code. The thing that bothers me is that when I run %%timeit, I don't get the results. For instace:

```
a=5
b=3

%%timeit
c = a + b
```

Now if I want to use c in the next cell, I get that c hasn't been defined.

```
print(c)
>>>NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Could you help me understand why this happens, why doesn't c get stored when the  magic %%timeit function is used in that particular cell?

Comment: "Cell"? You mean "line"? "Statement"? "Variable"?

Comment: Ah, looks like you're talking about IPython...!?

Comment: Yes, I should have made it clear, I'm using IPython/Jupyter with python 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you time code with `%%timeit`, the code you provide is executed within a separate namespace, and so its effects are not visible to your environment.

Comment: Ok, I see that it's a different namespace, but I'm not sure I understand why, what's the benefit of it?

The point of me writing c=a+b was to calculate c. Why did it have to take it to a different namespace so that I don't get the result?

Comment: You'd have to read the `timeit` library code to get that level of detail - I can tell you what is happening, but not why.

Comment: `timeit` may run your code many times, even thousands. In your example I get `10000000 loops, best of 3: 55.6 ns per loop`.  Typically I run the expression once to check the value, and then use `timeit` to test performance.

Answer (score 2):

> cell mode:
>
> ```
> %%timeit [-n<N> -r<R> [-t|-c] -q -p<P> -o] setup_code code code...
> ```
>
> In cell mode, the statement in the first line is used as setup code
> (executed but not timed) and the body of the cell is timed. The cell
> body has access to any variables created in the setup code.
>
> https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit

You're executing in cell mode, and the line is just *setup code*; which means it's not actually timed and its results are only accessible to the cell code following it.